# Parallel patterns supported specifically by AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

[msdn AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

**question**

What parallel pattern fits best around an AutoResetEvent?

**background**

When comparing options for synchronization between threads we might compare `AutoResetEvent` to `ManualResetEvent`. Consider these two distinctions:

1. AutoResetEvent releases at most one waiting thread.
2. AutoResetEvent resets *automatically* after one waiting thread is released.

It is important to note that if two threads are waiting and an `AutoResetEvent` fires twice, it is possible for a race condition to occur and only one thread is released. More locks could be used to protect from this condition - but the focus of the question is about what pattern `AutoResetEvent` does best (and perhaps this implies, what pattern it supports best on its own).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure we can talk about parallel patterns in this case. Patterns are on a much higher level of abstraction than mere synchronization mechanisms such as `AutoResetEvent`.

When we speak of parallel patterns we refer to generic methods of solving common parallelism problems like geometric decomposition of a data structure, parallel divide-and-conquer, producer-consumer and so on, which can be concretely implemented with a whole range of lower-level mechanisms and are language and platform agnostic.

`AutoResetEvent` is a .NET synchronization mechanism. It can be used together with the `Thread` class to implement one of the above patterns in a **concrete case**, but then this implementation can very well be substituted with pthreads and condition variables for example.

The way I was taught to view things when solving a parallelism problem was along these three steps, from abstract to concrete:

1. Identify parallel pattern(s) applicable
2. Identify a suitable algorithm to implement the pattern(s)
3. Identify suitable low-level mechanisms to implement the algorithm

**Edit**: Ok, after looking around my old "stuff" I've identified a pattern that can have an implementation using `AutoResetEvent`. For a good explanation of the problem check out my old question here: [Parallel application has random behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425706/parallel-application-has-random-behavior)

As you can see from the description, before starting to compute a row allocated to it, each thread must wait for a companion thread to process at least the first few items of the previous row. That means that each thread has to block at the beginning of each row assigned to it and wait for a signal. So assuming we have 3 threads processing the matrix, thread 0 would block at the beginning of rows 0, 3, 6... thread 1 at rows 1, 4, 7... and so on.

This wait-to-be-signaled behavior can be easily implemented using an `AutoResetEvent` per thread because each thread needs to block several times, meaning that we need to reset the event several times and there is no danger of it being signaled quickly in a sequence because the threads have to wait for each other to advance.

Comment: @payo: Well, as you can see from the three steps I mentioned in my edit, it would depend heavily on which pattern I choose and then which algorithm to support it. I'm going to come up with an example shortly. The main problem is that starting from the low-level mechanism itself it's pretty hard to generalize.

Comment: you make good points - but I feel the root of my question is still valid if perhaps worded poorly. Clearly the pattern is a higher level of abstraction - the point of this question is looking at solutions to implementations of those abstracted designs. Consider someone tries to implement pattern X with AutoResetEvent to handle the synch. You warn them, "That's going to be tricky, you'll need more signals here and here. If instead you were to use a Semaphore ..." So my question is, can you think of a pattern whose mechanism fits nicely with what AutoResetEvent provides out-of-the-box.

Comment: Sorry I had to move my comment - I wanted to clean up the text and was past 5 minutes. Please note I'm not trying to build a pattern from AutoResetEvent - that would be reading the question backwards, that would assume I'm following those steps in reverse. I'm not trying to solve a design problem. Yes it's a difficult question, and that's why I'm asking it :)

Comment: I think the question is: Could you give an example of a pattern that when implemented correctly and sensibly would naturally result in the use of `AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: @Mark Byers: That's exactly where I was trying to steer my soon-to-come edit. I'm cooking it now. :)

Comment: Your example does fit nicely. I wish we had a 'name' for this pattern :). Note also that your work also only had one thread waiting (per working thread). AutoResetEvent supports many waiting threads and promises only one will be released - a feature we wouldn't be taking advantage of in your example.

Comment: @payo: This pattern is officially called "Wavefront".

Comment: ah, you even point that out right at the top of your question (read too quickly).

Comment: @payo: I guess another pattern that could fit your requirement would be "single-producer multiple-consumer", where all the consumers can wait on a single `AutoResetEvent` and the producer uses it to signal that a new item was put in the buffer.